# Difference in Spring cloud eureka and spring data flow

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-netflix

We have a monolithic application with quite a few upstream and downstream application along with with a layer of ETL operations.

We are in process of breaking down this application in microservices. Application need to be scalable when it comes to onboarding more upstream and downstream applications. I'm new to microservices and I need some help is designing the application.

As of now we have decided to go with Spring Dataflow but that the same time we saw more discussion around Eureka + Netflix. Now I'm tittle confuse on use cases for these two.

Please help in understanding -

- How Spring Data flow is different from Spring Eureka?
- Few use cases where we should use Spring Data flow and Use cases where we should use Spring Eureka + Netflix.

Comment: Eureka is a service discovery system only. Data flow is a stream processing system

Comment: Thanks @spencergibb... So if I'm using data flow do I need Eureka as in data flow we can directly add microservices and use it...?